# Math Domain Error Python

Tags: python

I was trying to make a quadratic calculator using the formula, and I keep getting a Math Domain Error. Here us my code:

```
# coding: utf-8

from math import sqrt
a = 3
b = 9
c = 2

appaul = ((-1 * b) + sqrt((b ** 2) * (-4 * a * c))) / 2

print appaul
```

Comment: You are taking the sqrt of a negative number. `b^2 - 4ac < 0` => no solutions to your equation!

Comment: Typo in your quadratic formula - should be `(b**2) - (4*a*c)`, not the terms multiplied together.

Comment: try `from cmath import sqrt` - it'll allow you to operate on complex numbers.

Comment: @gtlambert  9^2 - 4*3*2 is greater than 0 , although OP's typo made it negative.

Answer (score 1):

This is a negative number. And you are trying to find square root of it.

```
(b ** 2) * (-4 * a * c)
```

To see it in effect, executing this

```
num = (b ** 2) * (-4 * a * c)
print num
appaul = ((-1 * b) + sqrt(num)) / 2    
print appaul
```

Results in -

```
-1944
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 118, in <module>
    appaul = ((-1 * b) + sqrt(num)) / 2
ValueError: math domain error
```

The negative number at the beginning is the number you are trying to find square root of.

Answer (score 0):

A correction to your code (Python 3):

## coding: utf-8

```
from math import sqrt

a = 3

b = 9

c = 2

appaul = (-b + sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c)) / 2*a

print(appaul)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
appaul = ((-1 * b) + sqrt((b ** 2) - (4 * a * c))) / 2
```

b^2 - 4ac, not b^2 * 4ac.

Answer (score 0):

Your `-` should come outside

```
>>> appaul = ((-1 * b) + sqrt((b ** 2) - (4 * a * c))) / 2
>>> print appaul
-0.725082782365
```

Answer (score -1):

u should use sqrt from cmath like the answer of Rogalki or u muss check, that Delta isn't negative before your caculation

Comment: for his case is delta positive. But please remember: for another cases could be delta negative. And u have the error again with the new formula